# MySQL multi-step GROUP BY without subquery

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm working on improving some queries I inherited, and was curious if it was possible to do the following - given a table `the_table` that looks like this:

```
  id   uri
  ---+-------------------------
   1   /foo/bar/x
   1   /foo/bar/y
   1   /foo/boo
   2   /alpha/beta/carotine
   2   /alpha/delic/ipa
   3   /plastik/man/spastik
   3   /plastik/man/krakpot
   3   /plastik/man/helikopter
```

As an implicit intermediate step I'd like to group these by the 1st + 2nd tuple of `uri`.  The results of that step would look like:

```
  id   base           
  ---+---------------
   1   /foo/bar      
   1   /foo/boo      
   2   /alpha/beta   
   2   /alpha/delic  
   3   /plastik/man
```

And the final result would reflect the number of unique tuple1 + tuple2 values, per unique `id`:

```
  id   cnt
  ---+-----
   1   2
   2   2
   3   1
```

I can achieve these results, but not without doing a subquery (to get the results of the implicit step mentioned above), and then select/grouping out of that.  Something like:

```
SELECT
  id,
  count(base) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    substring_index(uri, '/', 3) AS base
  FROM the_table
  GROUP BY id, base
)
GROUP BY id;
```

My reason for wanting to avoid the subquery is that I'm working with a fairly large (20M rows) data set, and the subquery gets very expensive.  Gut tells me it's not doable, but figured I'd ask SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a subquery -- you can use `count` with `distinct` to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT
    id,
    count(distinct substring_index(uri, '/', 3)) AS base
FROM the_table
GROUP BY id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cde986/1)

BTW -- this returns count of 1 for id 3 -- I assume that was a typo in your posting.

Comment: I'll take a closer look here in a bit, thank you.  And yes, you are correct about the typo in my question.  Fixed.

Comment: This is so simple, I can't believe I hadn't tried it. Thanks!